# Accessing constants in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a constants file.

```
var app = angular.module('ops.services');

app.constant('opsConstants', {
    GAID: 'UA1'
});

app.service('OpsConstantService', OpsConstantService);

OpsConstantService.$inject = ['opsConstants'];

function OpsConstantService(opsConstants){
    this.OPSCONSTANTS = opsConstants;

}
```

Now in a separate file, I am trying to access the same

```
DefaultConfig.$inject = ['OpsConstantService'];

function DefaultConfig(OpsConstantService) {  

    debugger;
```

I am getting `undefined` here.

How to resolve the same?

Comment: is there any console error?

Comment: @YorkChen No nothing.

Comment: what do you mean by "Now in a separate file", What is the separate file?

Comment: is `DefaultConfig` and `OpsConstantService` in the same module or not?

Comment: @AmayaSan Default Config is not under any module as such.

Comment: @ParvSharma Default Config is the separate file which is not under any module as such.

Comment: @StrugglingCoder Default Config should be registered in a module to get access to the angular's DI

Comment: @StrugglingCoder you have to register it in the module if you want to access the service